# Remove subseries (rows in a data frame) which meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data frame with a time series (column 1) and a column with values (column 2), which are features of each subseries of the time series. 
How to remove subseries which meet a condition?

The picture illustrates what I want to do. I want to remove the orange rows:
[image]

I tried to make loops to create an additional column with features that indicate which rows to remove but this solution is very computationally expensive (I have 10mln records in a column). Code (slow solution):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# sample data (smaller than actual df)
# length of df = 100; should be 10000000 in the actual data frame
time_ser = 100*[25]
max_num = 20
distance = np.random.uniform(0,max_num,100)
to_remove= 100*[np.nan]

data_dict = {'time_ser':time_ser, 
             'distance':distance,
             'to_remove': to_remove
             }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

subser_size = 3
maxdist = 18


# loop which creates an additional column which indicates which indexes should be removed.
# Takes first value in a subseries and checks if it meets the condition. 
# If it does, all values in subseries (i.e. rows) should be removed ('wrong'). 

for i,d in zip(range(len(df)), df.distance):
    if d >= maxdist:
        df.to_remove.iloc[i:i+subser_size] = 'wrong'  
    else:
        df.to_remove.iloc[i] ='good'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for create array of indexes by [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for remove duplicates.

Then use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) or if need new column [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
time_ser = 100*[25]
max_num = 20
distance = np.random.uniform(0,max_num,100)
to_remove= 100*[np.nan]

data_dict = {'time_ser':time_ser, 
             'distance':distance,
             'to_remove': to_remove
             }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print (df)
     distance  time_ser  to_remove
0   13.929384        25        NaN
1    5.722787        25        NaN
2    4.537029        25        NaN
3   11.026295        25        NaN
4   14.389379        25        NaN
5    8.462129        25        NaN
6   19.615284        25        NaN
7   13.696595        25        NaN
8    9.618638        25        NaN
9    7.842350        25        NaN
10   6.863560        25        NaN
11  14.580994        25        NaN
```

---

```
subser_size = 3
maxdist = 18

print (df.index[df['distance'] >= maxdist])
Int64Index([6, 38, 47, 84, 91], dtype='int64')

arr = [np.arange(i, min(i+subser_size,len(df))) for i in df.index[df['distance'] >= maxdist]]
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(arr))
print (idx)
[ 6  7  8 38 39 40 47 48 49 84 85 86 91 92 93]

df = df.drop(idx)
print (df)
     distance  time_ser  to_remove
0   13.929384        25        NaN
1    5.722787        25        NaN
2    4.537029        25        NaN
3   11.026295        25        NaN
4   14.389379        25        NaN
5    8.462129        25        NaN
9    7.842350        25        NaN
10   6.863560        25        NaN
11  14.580994        25        NaN
...
...
```

If need values in column:

```
df['to_remove'] = 'good'
df.loc[idx, 'to_remove'] = 'wrong' 
print (df)
     distance  time_ser to_remove
0   13.929384        25      good
1    5.722787        25      good
2    4.537029        25      good
3   11.026295        25      good
4   14.389379        25      good
5    8.462129        25      good
6   19.615284        25     wrong
7   13.696595        25     wrong
8    9.618638        25     wrong
9    7.842350        25      good
10   6.863560        25      good
11  14.580994        25      good
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.